# Build existing Docker image for another architecture without the original Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apple-m1, arm64

I've got an old Docker image for `linux/amd64` that I need to build for `linux/arm64` (to make it run on an M1 Mac).

The problem is that there is no `Dockerfile`. The image has been updated throughout the years using `docker commit` as changes have been made to it.

Is there a way of taking a new snapshot, but for another architecture (I guess not)? What options do I have otherwise?

The image in question is a custom setup of Cassandra for local development, and I'm really not sure what configuration it has, so I'd like to avoid setting it up from scratch if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way. Your current image contains binaries for amd64 that can't automatically be switched out for arm64. Your best bet is to look at the `docker history` for the image and try to replicate it. On the positive side, that'll also make it easier to make changes going forward.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks! Yeah, I agree that it would be great to have a Dockerfile going forward. I guess I could try to do a backup of the Cassandra schema, create a new Dockerfile and do a restore of that schema there. I think I'm most concerned about missing some configuration for Cassandra that is setup in the old image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the information from `docker history` in a readable manner the following (bash) command helped me. Just put your Image and Tag after `--no-trunc`

```
docker history --no-trunc IMAGE:TAG | tac | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f 5- | sed 's,^/bin/sh -c #(nop) ,,g' | sed 's,^/bin/sh -c,RUN,g' | sed 's,
 && ,\n  & ,g' | sed 's,\s*[0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]*\s*[kMG]*B\s*$,,g' | head -n -1
```

There is also an image as a nice tool: [Reference on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/dfimage)

Basically:

```
alias dfimage="docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm alpine/dfimage"
dfimage IMAGE:TAG
```